# Vimperator - How to emulate CTRL+F bar - search text within the page

Tags: vim, vimperator

There must be a keyboard shortcut within Vimperator that enabled me to search the page like CTRL+F in Firefox does, but so far I can't seem to find it.

Can anybody tell me what the keyboard shortcut is?

Comment: What would be the point of that addon if it didn't allow you to use basic vim-like commands like `/foo`?

Answer (score 1):

It's:

/

Right next to right SHIFT on most keyboards. Lost of other useful shortcuts can be found on http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7723/